# IPython notebook won't show plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

Not sure why this simple plot won't show.  simply shows an In[*] and won't finish loading the plot.  Can't find any info on what the * means.  Any help?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


r = np.arange(1,11)
v2 = 1.0/r

font = {'family' : 'serif',
    'color'  : 'black',
    'weight' : 'normal',
    'size'   : 18,
    }
plt.xlabel('$V*$', fontdict = font)
plt.ylabel('$Radii$', fontdict = font)
plt.plot(r,v2,lw=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you importing the modules properly? Can you post how you are importing the libs?

Comment: Can't replicate the issue, this plots fine for me, try a different backend, e.g. `%matplotlib inline`

Comment: Edited to show the imported modules

Comment: So I added in %matplotlib inline and it's working now. This is my first time using matplotlib, really sorry I guess I didn't do enoug research on how to get it working.  Thanks! I'm going to go look up what exactly that does now, so hopefully I wont make that mistake again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the iPython notebook [`%matplotlib` magic command](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-matplotlib) here is what you need to display the plot.

Basically, that command tells the notebook which backend to use when plotting with `matplotlib`, and sets it to work interactively. You usually will want to set that at the top of your notebook.

There are several options. A common one is

```
%matplotlib inline
```

which displays the plots right there in the iPython notebook.

Other options will depend on your system, but can include:

```
‘gtk’, ‘gtk3’, ‘inline’, ‘nbagg’, ‘notebook’, ‘osx’, ‘qt’, ‘qt4’, ‘qt5’, ‘tk’, ‘wx’
```

If you just set:

```
%matplotlib
```

without a gui option, it will use the default backend on your system (defined in your `.matplotlibrc` file).